# How do I use notifications in Solspace Rating?

Tags: solspace, solspace-rating

I'm using Rating and I'd like to receive a notification email whenever a review is placed. It seems that there already is such a thing, but I don't know how to configure it.
How do I select the email to which the email needs to be send?
And how do I specify which templates needs to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notification settings for each Rating form are set via the [notify](http://www.solspace.com/docs/rating/form/#notify), [admin_template](http://www.solspace.com/docs/rating/form/#admin_template) and [owner_template](http://www.solspace.com/docs/rating/form/#owner_template) parameters.

The values which `admin_template` and `owner_template` correspond to are the notifications you setup in the [Rating module control panel](http://www.solspace.com/docs/rating/control_panel/#notification_templates).

So, say you setup two different email notification templates called `admin_notification` and `owner_notification`, you could use these parameters on the [Rating Form tag](http://www.solspace.com/docs/rating/form/):

```
notify="admin@example.com" admin_template="admin_notification"
```

And/or:

```
owner_template="owner_notification"
```

The latter automatically sends an email using the specified template to the email address of the author of the entry being rated.